# Format float with two decimals without using .toFixed()

Tags: javascript, decimal, substring

I have a float,
var a = 324620.8

and I want it to look like this
a = 324620.80

This is my code so far,

```
    var a_float = a;
    var a_int = parseInt(a);

    d = a_float - a_int;
    if(d <= 0){
        a = a_int+'.00';
    }else{
        if(d < 0 && d > 0.1){
            a = a_int + d + '0';
        }else{
            a = a_float;
        }   
    }
```

This would works for only one decimal digit.
I want it to work when I have 2 decimal digits.

`.toFixed` would not work in some browsers.

Comment: Do not reinvent the wheel, use [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) instead. (Or search Stack Overflow, this question already has a few hundred duplicates here.)

Comment: The answer lies in long division.

Answer (score 4):

Answering the question in the title

> How to find how many decimal digits in a float?

Compare position of `'.'` to length of float as a *String*.

```
var x = 1.2345,
    x_str = x.toString(),
    decimal_digits = x_str.length - x_str.lastIndexOf('.') - 1;
decimal_digits === x_str.length && (decimal_digits = 0); // case no decimal
decimal_digits; // 4
```

Comment: found this question from a search and you answered my question and you are correct, this should be the correct/accepted answer to the question.  Their fault for wording it incorrectly

Comment: also, what exactly is happening on this line:    `decimal_digits === x_str.length && (decimal_digits = 0);`    I don't recognize this type of operator format.

Comment: The _logical AND_ `&&`, consider; `'a' && 'b' // 'b'`, `false && 'b' // false`. This is combined with a normal set `=` within parenthesis (so the compiler understands what is for _LHS_ of the `=`). ------ `decimal_digits === x_str.length` means `x_str.length - x_str.lastIndexOf('.') - 1  === x_str.length`, re-arrange, `x_str.lastIndexOf('.') === -1`, i.e. _LHS_ of `&&` is only true if there was no `.` in `x_str`

Answer (score 0):

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Bcep6/)
Use `toFixed("2");`

```
var f = 1.3454545;
f.toFixed(2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var decimal = 4.0;
var a = (decimal).toFixed(2); 


console.log(a); // outputs 4.00
```